# How to sort json data using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My $http response gives me the results in the below format:

```
$scope.rooms = {  
    '2B' : [    
        {"RoomEmailId":"2B-323@me.com","RoomName":"2B-323"},    
        {"RoomEmailId":"2B-123@me.com","RoomName":"2B-123"}     
    ],   
    '5A' : [  
        {"RoomEmailId":"5A-323@me.com","RoomName":"5A-323"},   
        {"RoomEmailId":"5A-123@me.com","RoomName":"5A-123"},  
        {"RoomEmailId":"5A-423@me.com","RoomName":"5A-423"}  
    ],  
    '1A' : [  
        {"RoomEmailId":"1A-323@me.com","RoomName":"1A-323"},  
        {"RoomEmailId":"1A-123@me.com","RoomName":"1A-123"},  
        {"RoomEmailId":"1A-423@me.com","RoomName":"1A-423"}  
    ]  
}
```

I want to sort this result in the below order:

```
$scope.rooms = {  
    '1A' : [  
        {"RoomEmailId":"1A-123@me.com","RoomName":"1A-123"},  
        {"RoomEmailId":"1A-323@me.com","RoomName":"1A-323"},  
        {"RoomEmailId":"1A-423@me.com","RoomName":"1A-423"}  
    ]  
    '2B' : [  
        {"RoomEmailId":"2B-123@me.com","RoomName":"2B-123"},  
        {"RoomEmailId":"2B-323@me.com","RoomName":"2B-323"}       
    ],  
    '5A' : [  
        {"RoomEmailId":"5A-123@me.com","RoomName":"5A-123"},  
        {"RoomEmailId":"5A-323@me.com","RoomName":"5A-323"},        
        {"RoomEmailId":"5A-423@me.com","RoomName":"5A-423"}              
    ],  
}
```

How to sort it by using javascript?

Comment: Your current data is an object, not an array. If you want it to be sorted you need to use an array. (Or process in `Object.keys($scope.rooms).sort()` order.) The nested arrays can be sorted using `.sort()` with an appropriate comparator. By the way, there is no JSON in your question, only objects and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is like this?`delete` and reassign value to the object instead.usage:`sort(rooms,by("RoomName","RoomEmailId"))`

### Code

```
function by(columns) {
    columns = typeof columns == "string" ? columns.split(",") : columns;

    function compare(a, b) {
        return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
    }

    return function (a, b) {
        for (var i in columns) {
            var p = columns[i];
            var it = compare(a[p], b[p]);
            if (it) {
                return it;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

function sort(o, comparator) {
    return Object.keys(o).sort().reduce(function (o, key) {
        var it = o[key];
        delete o[key];
        o[key] = it.sort ? it.sort(comparator) : it;
        return o;
    }, o);
}
```

### Test

```
test("sort keys", () => {
    let o = {b: 2, a: 1};

    expect(Object.keys(o)).toEqual(["b", "a"]);
    expect(sort(o, null)).toEqual({a: 1, b: 2});
    expect(Object.keys(o)).toEqual(["a", "b"]);
});

test("sort values", () => {
    let o = {b: [{value: 2}, {value: 1}], a: [{value: 4}, {value: 3}]};

    expect(Object.keys(o)).toEqual(["b", "a"]);
    expect(sort(o, by("value"))).toEqual({b: [{value: 1}, {value: 2}], a: [{value: 3}, {value: 4}]});
    expect(Object.keys(o)).toEqual(["a", "b"]);
});
```

### Demo

```js
var rooms = {  
    '2B' : [    
        {"RoomEmailId":"2B-323@me.com","RoomName":"2B-323"},    
        {"RoomEmailId":"2B-123@me.com","RoomName":"2B-123"}     
    ],   
    '5A' : [  
        {"RoomEmailId":"5A-323@me.com","RoomName":"5A-323"},   
        {"RoomEmailId":"5A-123@me.com","RoomName":"5A-123"},  
        {"RoomEmailId":"5A-423@me.com","RoomName":"5A-423"}  
    ],  
    '1A' : [  
        {"RoomEmailId":"1A-323@me.com","RoomName":"1A-323"},  
        {"RoomEmailId":"1A-123@me.com","RoomName":"1A-123"},  
        {"RoomEmailId":"1A-423@me.com","RoomName":"1A-423"}  
    ]  
};
function by(columns) {
    columns = typeof columns == "string" ? columns.split(",") : columns;

    function compare(a, b) {
        return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
    }

    return function (a, b) {
        for (var i in columns) {
            var p = columns[i];
            var it = compare(a[p], b[p]);
            if (it) {
                return it;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

function sort(o, comparator) {
    return Object.keys(o).sort().reduce(function (o, key) {
        var it = o[key];
        delete o[key];
        o[key] = it.sort ? it.sort(comparator) : it;
        return o;
    }, o);
}
console.log("unsorted rooms:",rooms);
console.log("sorted rooms:",sort(rooms,by("RoomName","RoomEmailId")));
```

Comment: This only works by accident. This behavior is not guaranteed by the JS script.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you've moved the keys around within the object. Object key-values are not sort-able, you'll need them to be in an array for that to happen. If you just wish to sort the arrays that are the values of those keys then you can `reduce` the Objects keys and return a new object as you require (this solution is nice since you won't be mutating your original `rooms` object)

```
const result = Object.keys(rooms).reduce((obj, roomKey) => {
  obj[roomKey] = rooms[roomKey].slice().sort((a, b) => a.RoomName > b.RoomName);
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Here it is in action:
http://jsbin.com/paqavaxako/edit?html,js,console